# Build output from Visual Studio 2010 external tools in output window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file

I run a batch file as an external tool (by adding it in Tools->External tools) in VS2010 (I've checked the "Use Output Window" option). This batch file performs compilation as in VS command prompt. The project that I'm working on has makefiles for various folders, so I use the mk command to build.
In the batch file, I set up the VS environment and then run the following commands:

```
cd $directoryWhichContainsFileToBuild
mk
cd main   //This directory contains the executable that is to be built
mk
```

I see the output of the first mk in the Output window but after that it just hangs. I also tried to use an echo after the first mk but even that doesn't get printed in the output window (the ones before it can be seen).
Somewhere I read that there is an issue with VS 2010 output window where it hangs after showing some output, although I couldn't really be sure that that is what's the issue here.

Do I need to enable some other VS setting? Has anybody else encountered this issue?
Thanks.

**Update**: I unchecked the "Use Output Window" and "Close on exit" option, and I see an extra statement: "Press any key to continue". On doing that however, their is no further processing of the batch file.

**Update2**: Got it to work by prefixing mk with "call".
Thanks all who tried.

Comment: I see you've solved it, but the (probable) "why" is because, presumably, `mk` is a batch file and simply _executing_ one batch file from another (which effectively is what the build script is) will **transfer** control to the second batch file and not return.  Using `call` will call the second batch file and return to the original when it finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing as a separate answer instead of an update in the question itself as many readers see the header and skim to the answer: got it to work by prefixing mk with "call". (@TripleHound has also posted the conceptual reason for it in the comment above.)

Answer (score 0):

It is always good in batch files to specify executables with full path and file extension instead of just the file name. This avoids often lots of problems.

Here was just `mk` used instead of `mk.bat`. Therefore on every compile the command line processor **cmd.exe** searches for **mk.*** and then checks if any of the found files have an extension listed in environment variable **PATHEXT**. The order of file extensions separated by a semicolon in **PATHEXT** defines the order of execution in case of a directory contains multiple **mk.*** files.

If a command being specified in a batch file not being an internal command of **cmd.exe** without path, command line processor searches first for a file with given name in current working directory. This is often one more cause of error. What is the current working directory on execution of the batch file?

Next if no file to execute can be found in current working directory, the command line processor searches in all folders being listed in environment variable **PATH** separated by semicolons.

So specifying in batch files edited only rarely an external application or another batch file with full path, file name and file extension, in double quotes if necessary because of 1 or more spaces in path or file name, helps command line processor to more quickly execute that application or batch file and avoids problems because of executable not found (unknown command).

Sure, when typing commands in a command prompt window, nobody wants to enter the executables with full path, name and extension. But for batch files it is always good to be not lazy and type files to be executed with full path and extension.

[TripeHound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2096401/tripehound) has given already the explanation why the observed behavior occurred here.

If a batch file is executed from another batch file without using command **call**, the command line processor continues batch execution in the other batch file and does never come back. In a C/C++ program this is like using `goto` with the difference that parameters can be passed to the batch file containing the further commands to be executed next.

But running from within a batch file another batch file with **call** results in continuation of execution below the line calling the other batch file once the other batch file reaches end, except command **exit** is used in the called batch file without parameter `/B`.

So the solution here is using:

```
cd /D "Directory\Which\Contains\File\To\Build"

call "Path\Containing\Batch\File\To\Build\mk.bat"

rem With mk.bat not changing current working directory change working
rem directory to the directory containing the executable to be built.
cd main

call "Path\Containing\Batch\File\To\Build\mk.bat"
```

BTW: **exit** exits command processor, **exit /B** exits just current batch file. I'll give you three guesses why the parameter is **B** and not a different letter. Yes, **B** is the first letter of **batch**.